# Angular 2 - Call parent's router-outlet from child component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Let's say my router-outlet is located in 'myParentComponent'.
The hierarchy of components / routes goes like this.

> myParentComponent > CompanyComponent > CompanyBranchComponent

What I am trying to do, is access the router-outlet which is in **myParentComponent**, from **CompanyBranchComponent** (I want to load CompanyBranchComponent in myParentComponent router-outlet)

'myParentComponent' template:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is my routing file: app.routing.ts:

```
 {
    path: '',
    component: myParentComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Parent'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'company',
        loadChildren: './components/company/company.module#CompanyModule'
      },
     ]
    }
```

The routing file of Company looks like:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: CompanyComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'Company'
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: 'branch',
            component: CompanyBranchComponent,
            data: {
                title: 'Branch'
            }
        }]
}
```

The problem with this is that **CompanyBranchComponent** expects it's own router-outlet. I don't want to load that component in new outlet, I want to load it in **myParentComponent's** outlet.

I have tried using outlet naming, but it didn't give me the result I wanted.

Comment: I'd suggest making an example of your application in https://stackblitz.com to illustrate what the issue is so someone can help you solve your issue faster

Comment: can you please post what have you tried with Named router outlet as i guess this will solve the issue for you